# C Stack data structure

Tags: c, stack

I have implemented a `Stack` data structure in C and I would like to know if there is something that could be improved.

Stack using linked list:

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

//Linked List based data structure.
typedef struct Stack {
    int data;
    int size;
    struct Stack *next;
}Stack;

/**
 * initStackWithData initializes a new Stack by allocating a new pointer with
 * the ammount of memory a Stack needs. Then after checking if the newly
 * created stack is NULL or not its values are initialized by using the value
 * from the parameters and setting the next Stack it points to to NULL.
 * This initial Stack will serve as the bottom of the stack so it will never
 * point to another Stack with its next property.
 *
 * @param val - Value to place in the Stack structures data property.
 *
 * @returns pointer to the just initialized Stack structure(object).
 */
Stack* initStackWithData(int val) {
    Stack *newStack = (Stack *) malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    if(newStack == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newStack->data = val;
    newStack->size = 1;
    newStack->next = NULL;

    return newStack;
}

/**
 * push is pushing a new value to the top of the stack. Since the Stack
 * structure is a LIFO(Last In First Out) the value pushed is stored into a new
 * Stack structure and the old head Stack (Top) is getting replace with the new
 * Stack created. That makes it so that the new Stack is the new top pointing
 * to the old top.
 *
 * @param **head - Pointer to the pointer of head, we use pointer to pointers to
 * make it easier by letting us change the entire head Stack from this function.
 * @param val - Value to place in the Stack structures data property.
 */
void push(Stack **head, int val) {
    Stack *newStack = (Stack *) malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    newStack->data = val;
    newStack->next = *head;
    if (!isEmpty(*head)) {
        newStack->size = newStack->next->size + 1;
    } else {
        newStack->size = 1;
    }
    *head = newStack;
}

/**
 * pop is removing the first element of the Stack. Since all Stacks are linked
 * through the next property pointing to the next Stack in the linked list it
 * can remove the current top and then make the new top become the next Stack
 * of the linked list.
 *
 * @param **head - Pointer to the pointer of head, we use pointer to pointers to
 * make it easier by letting us change the entire head Stack from this function.
 * @param val - Value to place in the Stack structures data property.
 *
 * @returns The data value from the removed Stack. Returns -1 if the Stack is
 * empty.
 */
int pop(Stack **head){
    if (isEmpty(*head)) {
        return -1;
    }

    Stack *newStack = (*head)->next;
    int retval = (*head)->data;
    free(*head);
    *head = newStack;

    return retval;
}

/**
 * peek is a function that lets the caller view the value of the element at the
 * top of the stack without removing it.
 *
 * @param **head - Pointer to the pointer of head, we use pointer to pointers to
 * make it easier by letting us change the entire head Stack from this function.
 *
 * @returns The data value found on the top of the Stack. Returns -1 if the
 * Stack is empty.
 */
int peek(Stack **head) {
    if (!isEmpty(*head)) {
        return (*head)->data;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * deleteStack is a function that lets the caller delete their entire Stack
 * structure by calling this function.
 *
 * @param **head - Pointer to the pointer of head, we use pointer to pointers to
 * make it easier by letting us change the entire head Stack from this function.
 */
void deleteStack(Stack **head) {
    Stack *newStack;
    while (!isEmpty(*head)) {
        newStack = (*head)->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = newStack;
    }
    free(*head);
}

/**
 * isEmpty checks if the Stack passed into the parameters is empty.
 *
 * @param *head - The Stack to check if empty or not.
 *
 * @returns 1 if the Stack is empty. Returns 0 if the Stack is not empty.
 */
int isEmpty(Stack *head) {

    if (head == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 * display loops through the entire Stacks linked list priting out every
 * data property found while looping through the entire list of linked Stacks.
 *
 * @param *head - The target Stack to loop through its linked elements.
 */
void display(Stack *head) {
    Stack *current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("Stack Data: %i, Stack Size: %i\n", current->data, current->size);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Here is my stack using array:

```
#include "ArrayStack.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define STACK_MAX 30

//Array based stack data structure.
struct ArrayStack {
    int top;
    int data[STACK_MAX];
};

/**
 * initWithData initializes a new ArrayStruct by allocating a new pointer with
 * the ammount of memory a Stack needs. Then after checking if the newly
 * created stack is NULL or not its values are initialized by using the value
 * from the parameters and setting the next Stack it points to to NULL.
 *
 * @returns pointer to the just initialized ArrayStruct.
 */
struct ArrayStack* initArrayStruct() {
    struct ArrayStack *newStack =
    (struct ArrayStack*) malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayStack));

    if(newStack == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newStack->top = -1;
    return newStack;
}

/**
 * pushToArrayStruct pushes a new integer value to the ArrayStruct provided in
 * the parameters. It first checks that the stack is not overflowing the array
 * size and if not proceeding with incrementing the top property and placing
 * a new value into the data property at the current top.
 *
 * @param *stack - The target stack to push a value to.
 * @param val - The target value to push into the array of the stack.
 */
void pushToArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack, int val) {
    if (stack->top >= STACK_MAX-1) {
        return;
    }
    stack->top = stack->top + 1;
    stack->data[stack->top] = val;
}

/**
 * pushToArrayStructEnd pushes a new integer value to the ArrayStruct provided
 * in the parameters. It first checks that the stack is not overflowing
 * the array size and if not proceeding with looping through the stacks entire
 * data array moving each element up one position in the stack and then places
 * the new value at the bottom of the stack at position 0.
 *
 * @param *stack - The target stack to push a value to.
 * @param val - The target value to push into the array of the stack.
 */
void pushToArrayStructEnd(struct ArrayStack *stack, int val) {
    if (stack->top >= STACK_MAX-1) {
        return;
    }

    int x;
    for (x = stack->top; x >= 0; x--) {
        stack->data[x+1] = stack->data[x];
    }
    stack->top = stack->top + 1;
    stack->data[0] = val;
}

/**
 * popFromArrayStruct removes the value at the top position of the stacks array
 * and reuturns it.
 *
 * @param *stack - The target stack to pop the top values from.
 *
 * @returns the value on the top of the stack. Returns -1 if the stack is empty.
 */
int popFromArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
    if (stack->top < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return stack->data[stack->top--];
}

/**
 * peekAtArrayStrut returns the top value of the array based stack
 * without removing it from the stack.
 *
 * @param *stack - Pointer to the target stack to peek at.
 * @returns the value located at the top of the stack.
 */
int peekAtArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
    return stack->data[stack->top];
}

/**
 * isEmptyArrayStruct checks if the array based stack is empty or not
 * and returns a true of false value depending on if it is or not.
 *
 * @param *stack - Pointer to the target stack to check if empty.
 * @return a true or false value depending on if the target stack is empty
 * or not.
 */
int isEmptyArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
    if (stack->top >= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * displayArrayStruct loops through the entire array based stack
 * printing out all the values within the stack.
 *
 * @param *stack - Pointer to the target stack to display values from.
 */
void displayArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= stack->top; x++) {
        printf("Stack Data: %i\n", stack->data[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's first look at your single-linked-list themed as a stack:

1. You don't ever use `.size`, so cut that.
2. You could call it `slist` for single-linked-list.
3. `initStackWithData` is a bad idea. Let them just declare an empty stack and push on that:

   ```
   Stack* stack = 0;
   push(&stack, val);
   ```
4. If you determine that a functions precondition is broken, that is a programmer-error and irrecoverable, thus there's just one thing to do:

   ```
   abort();
   ```

   Returning without doing anything or otherwise trying to mask the bug just makes properly diagnosing it unneccessarily difficult.
5. Why don't you return the result of the comparison directly in `isEmpty()`?
6. If you want to branch on a pointer pointing nowhere / somewhere, use `!pointer` resp. `pointer`. Much less boilerplate.

   ```
   p == NULL  ==>  !p
   p != NULL  ==>   p
   ```
7. C has something called a for-loop. Use it where appropriate.

   ```
   void display(Stack* stack) {
       for(; stack; stack = stack->next)
           printf("Stack Data: %i\n", stack->data);
   }
   ```
8. Do not cast the result of `malloc`. It's redundant. And avoid using `sizeof(type)`, it's error-prone.

   ```
   Stack *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
   ```
9. You forgot to check the result of `malloc` in `push`. Correct that.

Now let's look at your stack implemented with an array:

1. You forgot the convenience-typedef so you don't have to type `struct` all the time.
2. A compile-time capacity-restriction to 30 can be inconvenient. Why 30?
3. See the `malloc` and `sizeof`-advice above.
4. I wonder why you hang `Struct` at the end of all those functions... Didn't leaving out the typedef make you type those letters often enough?
5. Silently dropping a pushed value if the magic 30 is too small? Bad idea, I really don't want to debug that ever, see above for failed preconditions.
   Either make it dynamically extending, just `abort`, or at the very least return an error-indication to the caller, so he can do that.
6. If the stack is empty, at least add an assertion for debugging, if you don't want to burden release-mode with checking preconditions.

   ```
   assert(top >= 0);
   ```

   If you want to have it checked in release-mode too, either do a conditional `abort()` or compile with assertions enabled.

Comment: Hey great points, I just wonder if you could expands the points 4 and 6 for the linked list and point 5 and 6 for the array implementation.

Comment: Elaborated a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like these:

> ```
> int isEmpty(Stack *head) {
>
>     if (head == NULL) {
>         return 1;
>     }
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

> ```
> int isEmptyArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
>     if (stack->top >= 1) {
>         return 1;
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

can be respectively simplified to just one `return` statement:

```
int isEmpty(Stack *head) {
    return !head;
}
```

```
int isEmptyArrayStruct(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
    return stack->top >= 1;
}
```

This will also make it a little easier to modify them in the event that you decide to have them return `bool` instead.